# Images are invert on mac browsers

Tags: html, macos, css

We are facing a strange issue where images on Mac browsers showing inverted. SS below.

[image]

I have tried on my Mac system it is showing as expected. Unfortunately i do not have access to the mac where it is being shown as inverted.

Has anyone faced this issue?

Answer (score 2):

An image is inverted when the following css attribute is in effect:

```
filter: invert(100%);
```

Thus, you might be able to fix the problem with the following css:

```
img {
    filter: invert(0%) !important;
}
```

---

```css
img {
    transition: 500ms ease-in-out;
    }
    
img:hover {
    filter: invert(100%);
    }
```

```html
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/8NLsi1s.jpg" height="100" width="100">
```

Comment: This css was not applied to it. The issue was the images were higher in the height and width.